# The Expo CLI Web UI is deprecated, please use the Terminal UI instead

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, metro-bundler

What does mean this error when I open expo.

[image]

Comment: yes, and didnt help me

Comment: follow the blog, [Sunsetting the Web UI for Expo CLI](https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206)

Answer (score 0):

It means that the GUI (Graphical User Interface) is no longer maintained by the company. Use the CLI (Command Line Interface) to build your projects.

[Link on how to use it](https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/)